# Unity and UDP MulticastGroup

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, udp

I'm trying to listen in on a host that's sending over UDP using MultiCastGroup. In Unity the client starts but no message is ever received, but if I take the exact same code and drop it into a console application it works and I see the host's messages.

Here's what I've got:

```
public class UDPListener : MonoBehaviour
{
   IPEndPoint ip;
   private int port = 20000;
   private IPAddress group_address = IPAddress.Parse("233.255.255.255");
   private UdpClient client;
   string data;

   private void Start()
   {
       StartClient();
   }

   void StartClient()
   {
       Debug.Log("Starting Client");

       ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
       client = new UdpClient(ip);
       client.JoinMulticastGroup(group_address);

       client.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(ReceiveServerInfo), null);
   }

   void ReceiveServerInfo(IAsyncResult result)
   {
       byte[] receivedBytes = client.EndReceive(result, ref ip);
       data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedBytes);

       if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
       {
          Debug.Log("No data received");
       }
       else
       {
          Debug.Log(data);
       }

       client.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(ReceiveServerInfo), null);
   }
 }
```

I've also had the same result using client.Receive (works in console application but not in Unity) so I'm wondering if there's maybe some Unity setting I'm missing?

Comment: First, you are using a multicast group that does not belong to you. You should use a group in the Organization-Local Scope (`239.0.0.0/8`). Also, unless you have multicast routing configured on every router in the path between the two hosts, you cannot use multicast. That is why multicast will not work across the public Internet (you need to use a tunnel that supports multicast, not all do, to multicast across the Internet). Multicast routing is very different than unicast routing.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned this is for a local network only, but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, Windows update had turned my firewall back on which was blocking Unity :]